# Meteor: How can I decentralization user and admin with package account-ui and account-password

Tags: meteor

A both package account-ui and account-password is the great package can help we development quicly login and register method. But when I want to custom it I don't know how to make it. Detail that, now I want to decentralization user and admin, so I don't config this struct. How to I config, custom it.

Comment: i do not get the point of your question...

Comment: It mean that when i use account-ui and account-password package I can execute login and register very easy. But it can execute with client, can't with admin. Because I don't know how to config to go to admin pages. I don't know where I can write code. So it to hard for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the configuration into your javascript file using `Accounts.ui.config({});`

as it is shown [here](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown) (scroll all the way down)